# Assign same column value on a row repitition in mysql

Tags: mysql, primary-key, sql-insert

how to achieve this in mysql?

`Id` column is a `primary key`

if same occurances of value1 and value2 occurs,assign the same id value to the repeating row,as highlighted below

```
Id | Value1 | Value2
1  | a      | b
2  | c      | d
1  | a      | b
2  | c      | d
3  | e      | f
```

Comment: ID is a primary key as you say. You cannot assign repeating value to a primary key

Comment: Better you can add another one column for edited id values

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. A primary key dictates that that value (or values in the case of a composite key) must be unique within the table.

There are a couple of options available:

1. remove the primary key (and perhaps instead create an index) if
   the rows must be saved this way in duplicate
2. Do a query within
   application logic to determine whether the to-be-inserted row data
   already exists, and in such a case don't perform the insert
3. Create a query that does the same as (2), perhaps with an INSERT
   INTO .. WHERE NOT EXISTS clause